# WordPress - "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that" when adding a new taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress

I couldn't add a term in my custom taxonomy, I've checked the user role and everything is fine.

Whenever I add the term it says "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that."

[image: Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.]

Here is the code:

```
public function  create_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'City', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'City', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search City' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All City' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent City' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent City:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit City' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update City' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New City' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New City' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'City' )
      );    
     
    
      register_taxonomy('city', array('branches','post'), array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public'    => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'city' ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'with_front' => false
      ));
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure it's not a role/permission issue, have you tried creating a term using another user account yet?

Comment: @cabrerahector, Yes but still both user role can't create a term, btw I'm using a administrator role

Comment: I have the exact same issue. In the log file I get: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'edit_terms' of non-object in ...wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php on line 1062 
and some more lines for Trying to get property 'edit_terms' and more